# Jaxb Can't transfer xml to object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm new in jaxb, I have xml like this:

```
<testSuite name="suite1">
    <testCase name = "testCase1">
                <step name = "user">
                    <driverlicence>true</driverlicence>
                    <driversMinAge>18</driversMinAge>
                    <driversMinExperience>2</driversMinExperience>
                    <city_regestration>Boston</city_regestration>
                </step>
                <step name = "car">
                    <model>Ford</model>
                    <make>Focus</make>
                    <engineHorsepower>/resources/metadata/car_meta</engineHorsepower>
                    <modification>/resources/metadata/car_meta</modification>
                </step>
        <step name = "fullquota">
                    <driversListType>multidrive</driversListType>
                </step>
    </testCase>
   <testCase name = "testCase2">
                <step name = "user">
                    <driverlicence>false</driverlicence>
                    <driversMinAge>21</driversMinAge>
                    <driversMinExperience>11</driversMinExperience>
                    <city_regestration>LA</city_regestration>
                </step>
                <step name = "car">
                    <model>Audi</model>
                    <make>A6</make>
                    <engineHorsepower>user_meta</engineHorsepower>
                    <modification>user_meta</modification>
                </step>
        <step name = "fullquota">
                    <driversListType>nonemultidrive</driversListType>
                </step>
    </testCase>
</testSuite>
```

And Also I have class which I want to map to xml above:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="testSuite")
public class TestSuite {


    private TestCase testcase;


    public class TestCase {


        private Step step;


        public  class Step {

            Map<String, String> metaData = new HashMap<String, String>();


        } //End of StepClass

        @XmlAnyElement
        public void setStep(Step step) { this.step = step; }


    } //End of TestCase class

    @XmlElement(name="testCase")
    public void setTestcase(TestCase testcase) { this.testcase = testcase; }


}
```

This class has some inner classes and inner nested to inner classes.

I need to transfer my xml document to object  TestSuite class.  ONE IMPORTANT HERE IS THAT I NEVER KNOW HOW MANY AND WHAT KIND OF FILEDS I WILL JHAVE BETWEEN  `<step>` tag.
I need to have all node keys and nodes values beetween `step` tag

Comment: Personally, I recommend to first specify the XSD for the XML documents (a good thing anyway) and then to generate the JAXB classes from the XSD (eg. using a Maven plugin).

Comment: What error do you get?